# Ember.js route doesn't send state to a different controller, other than the route's default

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

So, I'm using a route to hold state for 2 backend API calls. What I'm basically trying to do is:

```
App.EnvironmentRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
   model: function(params) {
     return this.store.find('schedule', params.environment_id);
   },

  setupController: function(controller, model) {
     this.controllerFor('schedule').set('content', model);
  },                                                                                                                                                                                                           

  renderTemplate: function() {
     this.render('schedule');
  },
});
App.ScheduleController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({});
```

This is the example with only one model loaded, though ultimately what I want to do is:

```
    App.EnvironmentRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
       model: function(params) {
          return Ember.RSVP.hash(
              schedule: this.store.find('schedule', params.environment_id),
              other: this.store.find('other', params.environment_id)
          }            
       },

       setupController: function(controller, models) {
          this.controllerFor('schedule').set('content', models.schedule);
          this.controllerFor('other').set('content', models.other);
       },
```

(schedule - which is an array of models); what I want to achieve in the end is to delegate 2 backend calls to different controllers to different views/templates. The problem I currently have is even though I can see in the Chrome inspector the backend call being made and the data being returned properly, Ember.js doesn't seem to properly load it or set it into the ScheduleController. For what is worth I'm not even sure the data gets loaded into the model and I don't know how to verify that since the Route.model() method returns a promise.

I'm using ember 1.0.0 and ember-data 1.0.0-beta3.2

Comment: What you see in the inspector if you add console.log('model') to your setupController hook?

Comment: App.Schedule:ember270:null which most probably means that the model is empty. :|

Comment: And how is your server response?

Comment: Exactly as expected ... this.store.find('schedule', <id>) with the inspector showing exactly the data that has to be mapped to the model. (server returns underscore name attributes, the model has camel case ones), but that's the only difference.

Comment: Is there any reason you are using the EnvironmentRoute if you are pushing everything over to the Schedule*?  It's possible you are fetching a different instance of the ScheduleController, or you need to specify which controller you want the render to use.

Comment: I suspect it has something to do with the serialize method on the EnvironmentRoute which has the signature function(model, params) and the params is : ["environment_id"]

Comment: @kingpin2k: because ultimately I want to push state coming from 2 different REST calls to 2 different controllers (by using Ember.RSVP.hash)

Comment: BTW to analyze post promise, just do, model.then(function(realModel){
//here the model is for real
});

Comment: @kingpin2k: Thanks. Yeah, I don't get the model(s) I expect to receive, even when using .then(function(realModel){}). I am not sure if I made it clear, but this.store.find() returns a list of models (and that's why the ScheduleController is an ArrayController). Maybe that helps you in helping me :). Thanks!

Comment: @kingpin2k: I have updated with the piece of code I want to achieve, though I'm still stuck at the model part.